# How do I display a table of SQL data on the same page upon form submit in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

**Scenario:**

I have a form in in a C# page that is routed to a controller. This controller queries a MySQL database to shows all the in the database:

```
<p>Process an order</p>
<form id="retrievePastOrders" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/RetrievePastOrders" method="Get">
        <fieldset>
            <br><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Review Past Orders">
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the controller it gets to:

```
 [Route("/RetrievePastOrders")]
[ApiController]
public class RetrieveOrderController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult RetrievePastOrders([FromForm] Order order)
    {
        MySQLDAO mysqlDAO = new MySQLDAO();
        String resultsTable = mysqlDAO.ConnectToMySQLDatabase(order, "READ");
     
        return base.Content("<div> " + resultsTable + "</div> ", "text/html");
    }
}
```

**Question:**

This returns a page that just shows a table I built of all the all SQL data, but how do I get it so that this data just appears on the same page as the form? Is that possible?

I've tried looking at the docs for base.Content and seeing if people did similar things online, but all the examples were for C# MVC and I couldn't seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to have the method return a **RedirectResult**.

```
[Route("ProcessNewOrder")]
[ApiController]
public class ProcessOrder : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectResult ContentResult([FromForm] Order order)
    {
             //stuff

        return Redirect("https://whateveryoururlis")
    }
 }
```